# $_SESSION['firstname'] returns everytime blank

Tags: php, session

When i try to get the firstname with $_SESSION it returns blank.. 
Here is the PHP side of my home.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';


sec_session_start();


?>

<a href="#" title=""><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname'];?>
```

I'm not sure but i think there is a problem with the sec_session_start() function:

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';  

// The Below is set in a document which is included in the 
// functions document: include_once 'psl-config.php' with 
// define("SECURE", TRUE); 
$secure = SECURE;

// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;

// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}

// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);

// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);

session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Can someone help me with this :)

***Error Reporting:**
 I have enabled error reporting and it gives me this error now

> Notice: Undefined index: firstname in /----------/home.php on line 239

**I have fixed this error***

**Setting $_SESSION['firstname']**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();   
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($_SESSION['firstname']);
        $stmt->fetch();
            } else {
    // Not logged in 
    return false;
}
```

**The page is now white without any error reportings**

Also some pictures of the database: [image][image]

Comment: Enable error reporting if you haven't already.

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['firstname']` ?

Comment: You have to declare session start before anything. then you set the session variable. and then you can retreive it. you dont need a function that start a session. And we can not see where you set you session firstname var anywhere

Comment: try to add $_SESSION['firstname'] = 'MYNAME'; after the session_strat(); function and you should get something;

Comment: This is entirely the wrong way you should be setting sessions

Comment: @Martin When the page loads it runs the sec_session_start() function.

Comment: Then please can you refer back to @ksealey comment above, and answer that

Comment: @Martin I have fixed the error, I typed something wrong.. Anyways it's still empty. I have added the code where i set $_SESSION['firstname'] and added some pictures

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION);` show? Also try temporarily removing `session_regenerate_id()` due to potentially losing the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, I was missing a `}` at the end of the `set $_SESSION` script